# Transform a data table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have one table like :

```
A Team | A Captain | B Team | B Captain | C Team | C Captain

 X     | abc       |  y     |  def      |  z     | pqr

 1     | 123       |  4     |  456      |  7     | 789
```

And I want to transform it to the following structure:

```
TeamType | Team | Captain

  A      |  X   |  abc

  B      |  Y   |  def

  C      |  Z   |  pqr

  A      |  1   |  123

  B      |  4   |  456

  C      |  7   |  789
```

Comment: You have our approval. Go ahead :)

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the **DataTable**

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/46486/Pivoting-DataTable-Simplified) is a good example that you can refer to.

Hope this helps.